# How to toggle avoidHighways/avoidTolls in draggable directions Google maps API v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, draggable, directions

I did draggable directions according to Google manual:

```
ren = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer( {'draggable':true} );
ser = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

google.maps.event.addListener(ren, 'directions_changed', function() {
   // here I can load map, etc... everything works.
});
```

But, what should I do, if I want to change route options before next drag. I want exactly toggle avoidHighways and avoidTolls to true/false.
Is it even possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

Both properties are options of a directionsRequest, so you'll have to request the route again(based on the current origin/destination) with the desired options.